# Java replaceAll for separated comma String with regex

Tags: java, replaceall

I have this String:

```
String a = [MercadosArmados.GpoMerc-CTN3].[Mercado Marketing SNC].[Mk Alprazolam], [MercadosArmados.GpoMerc-CTN3].[Mercado Marketing SNC].[Mk Amantadina]
```

I need to extract just the 3rd [value] of every comma separated block. For example, I need to print:
Mk Alprazolam, Mk Amantadina

I'll put it in a textfield expression of a JasperReport so I need to achieve it in one line. Example:

```
a.substring(0, a.indexOf(",")).substring(a.substring(0, a.indexOf(",")).lastIndexOf("[")).replace("[", "").replaceAll("]", "")
```

this returns: Mk Alprazolam... but I need it for every comma separated block (it could be 1+).

I've tried some regular expressions with .replaceAll but can't achieve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Look in to string splitting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java You could split that string 2 times and get what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure `replaceAll()` solution:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\[[^\\]]*\\]\\.|[\\[\\]]", "");
```

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/noWokK/2) for demo.

*Explanation*

Initial text:

`[MercadosArmados.GpoMerc-CTN3].[Mercado Marketing SNC].[Mk Alprazolam], [MercadosArmados.GpoMerc-CTN3].[Mercado Marketing SNC].[Mk Amantadina]`

First it matches `[xxx].` and replaces them with nothing. That leaves:

`[Mk Alprazolam], [Mk Amantadina]`

It then also matches `[` and `]` and replaces them with nothing. Result:

`Mk Alprazolam, Mk Amantadina`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input string is always in the format you have mentioned (else you need to handle some corner cases), you can simply do

```
Arrays.stream(a.split(","))
            .map(str -> str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 2, str.length() - 1))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

1. We split the input string by `,`.
2. For each part (from above) extract the substring starting at last index of `'.' + 2` and ending at index one before the end of the string
3. Print each of them.

You can join the individual strings as

```
String result = Arrays.stream(a.split(","))
            .map(str -> str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 2, str.length() - 1))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" , "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to extract your desired info with a regex:

```
String a = "[MercadosArmados.GpoMerc-CTN3].[Mercado Marketing SNC].[Mk Alprazolam], [MercadosArmados.GpoMerc-CTN3].[Mercado Marketing SNC].[Mk Amantadina]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\[[^\\[]*\\]\\.){2}\\[([^\\[]*)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Will print:

```
Mk Alprazolam
Mk Amantadina
```

You can also test a regular expression [online](https://regex101.com/r/338l96/3).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex and take the 3rd (or the ones where the modulo of 3 equals 0) match from it

[`(?:((?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])))+`](https://regex101.com/r/noWokK/3)

This regex used lookaheads and lookbehind to see if there is a bracket before or after the targeted string.